# (Selenium/Python) Tracking the code 200 after clicking on the element

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, laravel-livewire

Good day to all of you. Please help me with my headache. After I click on the button/field, etc. (via selenium), a request is sent (which has the status "pending"). How can I track the status of 200 before selenium moves to the next field ? (if this moment does not track, it aborts the previous request, and the entry in the previously entered field is deleted). Thank you in advance!)
[Visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXX1l.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible/supported natively via selenium

you could use `requests` packages

something like this:

```py
url = 'http://www.google.com'
driver.get(url)
status_code = requests.get(url).status_code

status = True
while status:
    if status_code != 200:
        print("Status code is not 200")
        time.sleep(3)
    else:
        print("status code is 200")
        status = False
```